# What does OUT prefix mean in the type of a variable in an Oracle Pl/SQL procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

What does 'OUT' mean in the following Oracle PL/SQL code :

```
PROCEDURE ECHANGE_202 (pMessageExport OUT VARCHAR2) AS 
...
```

Comment: Did you look at [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/subprograms.htm#LNPLS659) to see what it means?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu - what you've shown isn't right; that assignment works for a function, not a procedure OUT parameter. You meant `ECHANGE_202(v_result);`, where `v_result` is declared as a string, right?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu your example of `v_result := echange_202();` would only work for a function. Instead it should be more like: `declare v_result varchar2(10); begin echange_202(v_result); end;`

Comment: Readd it with the correct format, though. It's kind of a shame that you can't edit comments after 5 mins for cases like this!

Comment: @Boneist I'll just leave it to you guys (& @AlexPoole), since you're more experienced ;) And yes,it is a shame we can't edit comments for more than 5 minutes

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu Don't do that! You'll miss out on learning stuff *{:-) Never be afraid to be wrong; we're all wrong sometimes (even Tom Kyte)! The key is to learn from it. I've learnt a great deal about Oracle just from trying to help people on forums... *{;-)

Comment: The documentation was not clear enough to me, that is why I came to ask here.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 types of variables that can be passed to a PL/SQL Procedure or function. They are:

```
IN - This variable is an input parameter to the function/procedure. You send some value to the function through this.

OUT - This is an output parameter. The function stores some data to this variable, which can be accessed by the caller after the execution of the function/procedure.

IN OUT - This variable is a combination of the above two types. This will send data to the function, and can be used outside too.
```